# req is undefined when using req.accept inside nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've recently come across a problem when working with the built-in `req.accepts`,  `req.acceptsLanguages`, `req.acceptsCharsets`, and `req.acceptsEncodings` functions in express.

I have an express middleware function like this:

```js
function acceptCheckpoint(acceptOpts) {
  // Calling the following function results in a TypeError.
  function checkAccept(req, res, opts) {
    let acceptFunction = null;

    switch (opts.whichAccept) {
    case "type":
      acceptFunction = req.accepts;
      break;
    case "lang":
      acceptFunction = req.acceptsLanguages;
      break;
    case "charset":
      acceptFunction = req.acceptsCharsets;
      break;
    case "encoding":
      acceptFunction = req.acceptsEncodings;
      break;
    default:
      acceptFunction = req.accepts;
      break;
    }

    return acceptFunction(opts.acceptedTypes);
  }

  return (req, res, next) => {
    const accepted = [];

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(acceptOpts).forEach(key => {
      if (key === "ignoreAcceptMismatch") { return; }
      const acceptsType = checkAccept(req, res, {
        whichAccept: key,
        acceptedTypes: acceptOpts[key]
      });
      accepted.push(acceptsType);
    });
    if (accepted.some(type => !type) && !acceptOpts.ignoreAcceptMismatch) {
      res.type("html");
      res.status(406);
      res.send("<h1>406 Not Acceptable.</h1>");
      return;
    }
    next();
  };
}
```

Which, in theory, should work. But the program keeps complaining and logs this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
    at new Accepts (/Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/node_modules/accepts/index.js:37:22)
    at Accepts (/Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/node_modules/accepts/index.js:34:12)
    at req.accepts (/Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/node_modules/express/lib/request.js:133:16)
    at checkAccept (/Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/Lib/middleware.js:208:12)
    at /Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/Lib/middleware.js:216:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/Lib/middleware.js:214:44
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/hortoncheng/Desktop/Programs/colonialwars/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

The thing is, when I use `req.accepts` or one of those `.accepts` functions in the main function (`acceptCheckpoint`), like this:

```js
// Pretend we're in acceptCheckpoint...
// This works.
accepted.push(req.accepts("html"));
```

It works. And, when I log the `req` object in either of those functions, it returns the expected value. I've also tried logging the `req` object in the `request.js` file of the express module, and there, it returned `undefined`. So that led me to believe that it was a problem with express itself. I tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules, and then running `npm install`. Didn't fix it. And yes, I'm calling the express middleware function correctly. Any idea why this is happening?

I'm using express v4.17.1, Node.JS v12.18.1, and NPM v6.14.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is presumably trying to get `req` from its `this` context. But you're not passing functions with context.

Change this line:

```
return acceptFunction(opts.acceptedTypes);
```

to:

```
return acceptFunction.call(req, opts.acceptedTypes);
```

The first argument to the `call()` method is the object that should be used as `this` in the called function.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the problem was something about context, but I wasn't sure :D.